# ViewModel, LiveData with Firestore causing StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am fetching a collection from firestore and displaying in recyclerview. The collection is small only 2 documents with text less than 10 characters.When I display it in recylcerview without using architecture design patterns it works fine but if I implement it with viewmodel and livdedata I get  stack size 8MB error and app crash. I have searched for a day couldn't find anything relevant.

fetchNotes() is called repeatedly and Logs within addOnSuccessListener() dont hit.

I'll add repository once this works.

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val fab by lazy { findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.floatingActionButton) }
private val homeAdapter by lazy { HomeAdapter(ArrayList<Note>(),this) }
private val homeRecylerView by lazy {  findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.homerecyclerview)}
private val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
    initUI()
    initRecyclerView()
    initViewModel()


}

 private fun initViewModel() {
    homeViewModel.getNotes().observe(this, Observer<List<Note>> { notes ->
        homeAdapter.notes = notes
        homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })

}

class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
var tempList:MutableList<Note> =   mutableListOf()
fun getNotes(): LiveData<List<Note>> {
    return notes
}

private val notes: MutableLiveData<List<Note>> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<List<Note>>().also {
        fetchNotes()
    }
}

fun fetchNotes(): MutableLiveData<List<Note>> {

     FirebaseUtils.db().collection("notes").document(
          FirebaseUtils.auth().currentUser!!.uid
      )
          .collection("usernotes")
          .get()
          .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
              for (document in documents) {
                  tempList.add(document.toObject(Note::class.java))

              }
              notes.setValue(tempList)
          }
          .addOnFailureListener { exception ->


          }

    return notes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.It was due to recursion as I am not familiar with livedata.I fixed it as

```
 val notes: MutableLiveData<List<Note>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<List<Note>>()
    }
```